# cURL PHP - load a fully page

Tags: php, curl

I am currently trying to load an HTML page via cURL. I can retrieve the HTML content, but part is loaded later via scripting (AJAX POST). I can not recover the HTML part (this is a table).

Is it possible to load a page entirely?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: I don't believe curl has the ability to execute javascript in its retrieval of html content

Comment: I didn't see it possible because ajax is part of javascript which either a web browser or something like that  analyzes and runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.

CURL does nothing more than download a file from a URL -- it doesn't care whether it's HTML, Javascript, and image, a spreadsheet, or any other arbitrary data; it just downloads. It doesn't run anything or parse anything or display anything, it just downloads.

You are asking for something more than that. You need to download, parse the result as HTML, then run some Javascript that downloads something else, then run more Javascript that parses that result into more HTML and inserts it into the original HTML.

What you're basically looking for is a full-blown web browser, not CURL.

Since your goal involves "running some Javascript code", it should be fairly clear that it is not acheivable without having a Javascript interpreter available. This means that it is obviously not going to work inside of a PHP program (*). You're going to need to move beyond PHP. You're going to need a browser.

The solution I'd suggest is to use a very specialised browser called [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). This is actually a full Webkit browser, but without a user interface. It's specifically designed for automated testing of websites and other similar tasks. Your requirement fits it pretty well: write a script to get PhantomJS to open your URL, wait for the table to finish rendering, and grab the finished HTML code.

You'll need to install PhantomJS on your server, and then use a library like [this one](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/) to control it from your PHP code.

I hope that helps.

<sup>(*) yes, I'm aware of the PHP extension that provides a JS interpreter inside of PHP, and it would provide a way to solve the problem, but it's experimental, unfinished, would be still difficult to implement as a solution, and I don't think it's a particularly good idea anyway, so let's not consider it for the purposes of this answer.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way you can do that is if you make a separate curl request to ajax request and put the two results together afterwards.